# Basic signup form

Tags: php, mysql

I have create a sign-up form which receives username, email and password.
I coded like this:

```
include_once 'sqlConnect.php';

$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$eMail = $_POST['eMail'];
$passWord = $_POST['passWord'];
$day = date("d-m-Y");
$time = date("h:i:sa");

$dbINSERTuser = 'INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
        VALUE ('$userName', '$eMail', '$passWord', '$time')';

$result = mysql_query($dbINSERTuser);

if ($result) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
    echo mysql_error($dbINSERTuser);
}
```

In the end, it gave me this error:

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$userName' (T_VARIABLE) in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\Project EVO 1.0\signup.php on line 17**

I have been looking at this for hours and still not finding any solution. Please help!

Comment: Please include your code. This is probebly just a syntax error. But we can't help you with that without your code.

Comment: where is the code of signup form????

Comment: where is the code what you asking for ???man

Comment: Please paste the code of your singup form.

Answer (score 2):

PHP will evaluate variables values in the string, only when your string is wrapped with double quotes.

Change this:

```
$dbINSERTuser = 'INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
        VALUE ('$userName', '$eMail', '$passWord', '$time')';
```

To this:

```
$dbINSERTuser = "INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
        VALUE ('$userName', '$eMail', '$passWord', '$time')";
```

But be aware - this code is vulnerable to SQL injections!

UPDATE:
Learn how to use PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to make you queries safe.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `'` with `"` in your insert query

```
$dbINSERTuser = "INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
        VALUE ('$userName', '$eMail', '$passWord', '$time')";
```

To prevent sql injection use

```
$dbINSERTuser = "INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
        VALUE ('".$userName."', '".$eMail."', '".$passWord."', '".$time."')";
```

IN mysqli you can use like that way

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$eMail = $_POST['eMail'];
$passWord = $_POST['passWord'];
$day = date("d-m-Y");
$time = date("h:i:sa");

$dbINSERTuser = "INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
        VALUE ('".$userName."', '".$eMail."', '".$passWord."', '".$time."')";
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Read [mysqli manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: I gave me this error when I did what you suggested: **Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in G:\XAMPP\htdocs\Project EVO 1.0\signup.php on line 19**

Comment: Yeah use PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to `concat` string
change

```
$dbINSERTuser = 'INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
    VALUE ('$userName', '$eMail', '$passWord', '$time')';
```

to

```
$dbINSERTuser = 'INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
    VALUE (' . $userName . ', ' . $eMail . ', ' . $passWord . ', ' . $time .')';
```

Comment: This will cause an error. To insert string values in MySql you need to wrap them with single quote ' - there is not wrapping single quote in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbINSERTuser = 'INSERT INTO user_info (Username, Email, Password, Time)
    VALUE (''.$userName.'', ''.$eMail.'', ''.$passWord.'', ''.$time.'')';
```

Change as above

Comment: This will cause an error. To insert string values in MySql you need to wrap them with single quote ' - there is not wrapping single quote in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<?php
  $userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
  $eMail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eMail']);
  $passWord = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passWord']);
  $day = mysql_real_escape_string(date("d-m-Y"));
  $time = mysql_real_escape_string(date("h:i:sa"));

?>
```